# Handling large images in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to display a very large image in an HTML page. However, the image takes several seconds to render. Is there a way that I can render this image chunk by chunk as it loads instead of having to wait many seconds to see the full image all at once?

```html
<img src="https://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/simple?i=Who+composed+Bohemian+Rhapsody%3F&appid=DEMO">
```

Or is there another method of doing this that will make this image render faster in HTML?

Comment: `data:text/html,<img src="https://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/simple?i=Who+composed+Bohemian+Rhapsody%3F&appid=DEMO%22%20/%3E` does renders chunk by chunk!

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to implement this into HTML?

Comment: I meant, if you are using `img` tag, it will by default display the image as and when part of the image is arrived from server. To see it in action, copy/paste the follow text in **browser address bar** and hit enter.  `data:text/html,<img src="https://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/simple?i=Who+composed+Bohemian+Rhapsody%3F&appid=DEMO%22%20/%3E`

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to have this work the same way, but in an img tag?